# How can I detect a QEMU image?

Tags: qemu

I have a form where user can upload images (images of different OS).
How can I detect whether the image is QEMU image of type "qcow2" ?

Comment: maybe with `qemu-img check`?

Comment: @CrApHeR It would be great if you can explain how to use qemu-img check function. I just edited the question, I need a checker for qemu image of type "qcow2".

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood, `qemu-img check` is to check if the image has errors.  To get the image format you can use `qemu-img info`.  In the answer area I added a complete example.

Comment: the linux "file" command should work.

Answer (score 10):

You can use `qemu-img info` to check the image format.

`qemu-img info image-qcow.qcow2`

the result will be something like this

```
image: image-qcow.qcow2
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 10G (10737418240 bytes)
disk size: 136K
cluster_size: 65536
```

Source: http://lnx.cx/docs/vdg/html/ch02s03.html

After that, if you want to get the file format you can parse the output to get it.

Hope this helps

Comment: I found that the `.qcow2` file was locked buy `libvirt` and it was nesessary to `kill -9` the process.  I shouldn't have needed to do that.  For some reason `libvirt` remained loaded (Ununtu, Plasma system).